# QML listview Overscrolls

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a horizontal listview as given in the image[image: initial state]

Now when I scroll it the listview gets overscrolled as in the below image
[image: overscoll]

What I actually need is even if the drag is more , the last element should stay at the end as in the below image[image: correct scroll]

How can I do that.

**EDIT**

ListView Source

```
ListView{

        id: list
        width: 500
        height: 100
        clip: true
        //anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        //anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "#00000000" ;border.color: "red" ; radius: 5 }
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: ListModel{
            id: listModel
            ListElement{ name: "File"}
            ListElement{ name: "Edit"}
            ListElement{ name: "Build"}
            ListElement{ name: "Debug"}
            ListElement{ name: "Analyze"}
            ListElement{ name: "Tools"}
            ListElement{ name: "Window"}
            ListElement{ name: "Help"}
        }

        delegate: Button{
            borderColor: buttonBorderColor;buttonColor: buttonFillColor
            width: 100;height: 100 ;labelSize: 18
            label: model.name
            onButtonClick: {
                list.currentIndex = model.index;
                console.log("ListView Button clicked" + model.index)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide demo application?

Comment: Are you sure that your Button is Button from QtQuick.Controls? Last one doesn't have label and labelSize properties.....

Comment: Its not in QtQuick.Controls its a custo button. But I think that the "Button" is not the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Have you found the solution for it?

Comment: I don't remember what I did to fix it.Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the `ListView` to stop at the object bounds by setting its `boundsBehavior` property:

`boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds`

By default, objects that inherit `Flickable` overshoot the bounds and move back.

See the [`boundsBehavior` property description](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-flickable.html#boundsBehavior-prop) on the Qt website.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think when this question was asked, it was based on QtQuick 1.x controls. Now, with QtQuick 2.x some of the properties have changed their names. Anyhow, to fix the problem, I only had to comment out the following property:

```
        //highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
```

To mimic the original look, I updated the highlight delegate, add a horizontal `ScrollBar` and redid the `Button` delegate.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 500
        height: 100 + 20
        clip: true
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        //highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
        highlight: Rectangle {
             color: "#00000000"
             border.color: "steelblue"
             border.width: 2
             radius: 5
        }
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: ListModel{
            id: listModel
            ListElement{ name: "File"}
            ListElement{ name: "Edit"}
            ListElement{ name: "Build"}
            ListElement{ name: "Debug"}
            ListElement{ name: "Analyze"}
            ListElement{ name: "Tools"}
            ListElement{ name: "Window"}
            ListElement{ name: "Help"}
        }
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            height: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        delegate: Button {
            background: Item {
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 2
                    color: "#ccc"
                    radius: 5
                }
            }
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: model.name
            onClicked: {
                listView.currentIndex = model.index;
                listView.forceActiveFocus();
                console.log("ListView Button clicked" + model.index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAGfnicjVTLbtswELz7Kwj1kqCAogToRUUPtusgAVK0eaA909RGJrziCnzUcQL%2FeylbovWwUe1BIGeHXGqWQ1mUpC17tI9OivVEdqbxnJTVhKaPP%2FAtOWsmv3gO7GPCfDxIY39L2NTTKmSWMqzhAG5kZlcp%2B5IkAVqBzFc2ZddJwj6zm2NCoCxTZrWDABnFyx%2BUQRoKxs8eeqF7C0VgcSVWpE0sQFnQ9yplJdd%2BHAhXVytfE6u6T1zl0N%2FSaiksbhfqlbSAPeV43GblLSHSxsydrvauDtA7bGCm7AmE9bsgtPQ5%2FCMh6ZRFn5I6om5%2BSToDHTc0YwFwiQ5O02p1b7pJzTPpjBc9wLuBVP4j3327Oc73ojWSDRJhpcc9wK0k1ZLuLtADsfDi4oFS6YxdBZpbsk91MtWCBULhq3wwxQvfoehWIkS7%2F9IWmbQjaDMnMRvB%2Bw5Ll4%2FgTRXH7fuYA76Qt9UI3h%2BpMtqMIN4Bli3acfQsvINxxnWrk%2BkR7d3HxostF1ZREkqxbS2Lp7jhW%2FNTnajo%2Bwg5t%2F5UM2ctqV6JJRfrXJNTvvGVafqO8HHWLXU0l%2FZVIg68fYpYcJ1LZQbOqCOYUAgRnWQMLTT87%2BGstuN1kpwUuY9bePPo3i5x1dZOktTc92ANXrWhKM0zG4v6MVIZvLFv9V6ymn09v2j%2FyE2FlX%2FhloQzF5dDsiBlCCFGyi%2Bi8NjXDRaHk0X%2B%2BW5VvDyjzGG0m%2Bwm%2FwCk%2BsMr)